# Как проверить, что время относится к нужному диапазону?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Есть 2 объекта `datetime.time`. Мне нужно проверить, что в первый попадает в диапазон получаса в любую сторону от второго. Как мне это сделать, с учетом того, что `timedelta` нельзя использовать с `time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
from datetime import time, timedelta, datetime as DT

def is_in_interval(tm, int_time, delta=timedelta(minutes=30)):
    def to_dt(tm):
        return DT.combine(DT.today(), tm)
    return to_dt(int_time) - delta <= to_dt(tm) <= to_dt(int_time) + delta
```

---

Пример использования:

```
In [162]: is_in_interval(time(14, 33), time(15, 3), timedelta(minutes=30))
Out[162]: True

In [163]: is_in_interval(time(14, 33), time(15, 4), timedelta(minutes=30))
Out[163]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не указал это в вопросе, но кроме просто True или False мне нужны для дальнейшего использования и сами границы временного интервала. Поэтому я написал функцию, которая переводит время в минуты от 0 часов, прибавляет к нему временной интервал, проверяет не выходит ли время за границы дня и переводит обратно в объект `time`.
Может пригодится кому.

```py
from datetime import time

def time_to_minutes(time):
    return time.hour * 60 + time.minute


def minutes_to_time(minutes):
    h = minutes//60
    m = minutes%60
    return time(h, m)


def get_time_borders(target_time, time_delta):
    """Возвращает верхнюю и нижнюю границу времени
    (на time_delta в обе стороны от текущего)"""
    minutes_in_a_day = 60 * 24

    if time_to_minutes(target_time) > time_delta and (time_delta + time_to_minutes(target_time)) < minutes_in_a_day:
        low_border_in_minutes = time_to_minutes(target_time) - time_delta
        high_border_in_minutes = time_to_minutes(target_time) + time_delta

    elif (time_delta + time_to_minutes(target_time)) > minutes_in_a_day:
        low_border_in_minutes = time_to_minutes(target_time) - time_delta
        high_border_in_minutes = time_delta - (minutes_in_a_day - time_to_minutes(target_time))

    else:
        low_border_in_minutes = minutes_in_a_day - (time_delta - time_to_minutes(target_time))
        high_border_in_minutes = time_to_minutes(target_time) + time_delta

    low_border = minutes_to_time(low_border_in_minutes)
    high_border = minutes_to_time(high_border_in_minutes)

    return low_border, high_border
```